# How show ListView in ActionBarTab?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-viewpager, android-fragmentactivity

I created `ActionBarTab` and i need add `ListView` in witch `tab` that `ListViews` have difference data.
But i cant show my `listView` in `Tabs` .

`MainActivity.xml` :

```
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity  implements ActionBar.TabListener{
    static String [] Years;
    static ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    static ListView Lists;
    public static Context context;
    public static Activity activity;

    AppSectionsPagerAdapter mAppSectionsPagerAdapter;
    ViewPager mViewPager;
    private String[] tabs = { "tab 1", "tab 2", "tab 3","tab 4","tab 5" };

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
mAppSectionsPagerAdapter = new AppSectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();

        actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);

        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mAppSectionsPagerAdapter);
        mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
            }
        });

        for (int i = 0; i < mAppSectionsPagerAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
                    actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tabs[i])
                            .setTabListener(this));
        }
    }
@Override
    public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    }

    public static class AppSectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public AppSectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int i) {
            switch (i) {
                case 0:
                    Years = context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.YEAR); 
                    Lists = (ListView) activity.findViewById(R.id.list);
                    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, Years);
                    Lists.setAdapter(adapter);
                case 1:

                case 2:

                case 3:

                case 4:

                default:

                     return null;
 }
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 5;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return "Section " + (position + 1);
        }
    }
    }
```

NOTICE : In `switch case 0 :` I can't show `ListView` .

`activity_main.xml`  :

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

`simple_list_item_1.xml`  :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:paddingLeft="6dip"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
```

This is my `string-array` in `string.xml`, I fill my `listView` from here :

```
<string-array name="YEAR">
    <item>1992</item>
    <item>1993</item>
    <item>1994</item>
    <item>1995</item>
    <item>1996</item>
    <item>1997</item>
    <item>1998</item>
    <item>1999</item>
</string-array>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK . create a `fragment_section_listview.xml` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
        <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Notice : Delete `ListView` from `activity_main.xml` change it to :

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Then create a `class` in your `MainActivity` :

```
public static class LstView extends Fragment{
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_section_listview, container, false);

        Years = context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.YEAR); 
        Lists = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.list);
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, Years);
        Lists.setAdapter(adapter);
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

Then `write` this in your `switch case`:

```
 switch (i) {
   case 0:
     return new LstView();
      Other Code .....
```